# "You approved edits on something that clearly wasn't an answer"

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-suspension

I went in to **review** just now to get the warning:

> You approved edits on something that clearly wasn't an answer
>
> Come back in 2 days to continue reviewing.

The warning had a [link to this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5166965) that I had previously approved.

So my question is, why?  Who makes those determinations?  As I understand it, it doesn't matter if the item being approved for an edit is an answer or not.  The review process for edits doesn't give you any context, so how would a reviewer know if was an answer or not anyway?

EDIT:

Thank you all for your answers. Yes, I see that in context, it is a bad answer.  But that's my point.  There are a lot of different review processes, and I didn't think that it should matter whether it's a good contextual post or not.  Other reviews will catch that and flag it as such.  For edit reviews, it's simply determining if the edit is valid or not, not whether the post it good or not.

Just looking at the edit screen, it doesn't even tell you if it's a question or an answer (that I've ever noticed). If the workflow of an edit review required more context, then why isn't that information added to the review page?

Comment: The review screen does indicate that it's an answer - see the "answered 5 hours ago" tag under the original version, and the "C programming language help me?" text is a link to the original page so you can see the full context.

Comment: Some related discussions about these kinds of edits over at Meta.SE: ["Is “don't polish turds” a valid edit rejection reason?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155961/is-dont-polish-turds-a-valid-edit-rejection-reason) , ["Spam-polishing audits"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223141/spam-polishing-audits)

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks, Brad.  I'll be sure to review those.

Comment: @NathanA - I'm not saying this is as bad as those, just that they're talking about something in the same ballpark and how to react to it.

Comment: @BradLarson Ya, I wouldn't put it in the same ball park.  Spam and Ads are easy to see without any context. This particular edit was much harder to catch.  To me, it looked like a question, and as such, while it may not have been formed very well, I didn't see how it was my job as an edit reviewer to stop the edit.  But now having considered the effect it has on the edit author, and encouraging him to continue these bad edits, I see why I need to be more careful in these cases. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: I agree that it is sometimes hard to distinguish.  I thought I was reviewing an edit on someone's question-- it ended up being a question posted as an answer.  It's ridiculous that the post type isn't called out in a more visible format.

Comment: The suggested edit queue has severe problems with low quality reviewers, and moderators are using review bans more widely these days when they see something wrong.  It's only temporary, learn from it and review more thoroughly next time.

Comment: I feel for you.  Some questions are formatted or spelled so poorly that I can only ***comprehend them*** (see the forest for the trees, so to speak) after having extensively edited the text.  Then when I read it back I think *"Still utter rubbish, I'll just vote to close"*.

Comment: @ps2goat: make a feature request if you think so, don't make one if you think its not worth the effort..

Comment: @PlasmaHH, how do I make a feature request?

Comment: I had almost a similar problem a while back. [kalina](http://stackexchange.com/users/1546021/kalina?tab=accounts) noted [the difference between a suggested edit on an answer and on a question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8293/8698).

Comment: @ps2goat: A good meta post with feature-request tag should be sufficient. Search some for examples.

Comment: @ps2goat: I would be in full favor of this feature request. I made a mental note of it a number of times while doing edit reviews, but missed to act on it. Having to scroll to the bottom and picking out the small text to see if I'm reviewing a question or an answer is very inconvenient. Other review queues show Question or Answer in big writing at the top.

Comment: Feature request was made: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265992/can-the-type-of-post-being-reviewed-be-displayed-more-prominently

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> So my question is, why? Who makes those determinations?

Diamond moderators make those determinations (usually after someone else alerts us to the problem).

> As I understand it, it doesn't matter if the item being approved for an edit is an answer or not.

Yes, it does matter. People shouldn't be wasting their time and yours by suggesting minor edits to posts that should just be deleted.

> The review process for edits doesn't give you any context, so how would a reviewer know if was an answer or not anyway?

In that specific case, you'd read the post. It's clearly a question that someone typed into the "Your Answer" box.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please see my edit above.

Comment: `People shouldn't be wasting their time and yours by suggesting minor edits to posts that should just be deleted.` If it's the responsability of the person reviewing edits to screen the post, why isn't there a `[Flag Post]` button on the review screen?

Comment: @MrLore There's a link to the post itself on the review screen. A flag link would be used very little.

Comment: When reviewing edits -- there is no such option as recommending deletion

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I disagree and find this pure speculation. I never did statistics but my feeling is that a big part of the posts I flag is out of some review queues. There are also review queues where you can not comment, vote etc. and I find all these differences in interface rather arbitrary. Sure you can always open the original post, but *why do you have to?* What is the benefit of not having the same interface to interact with those posts everywhere? In either case though the difference in the interface should not influence your action (i.e. to flag, or not to).

Comment: @PlasmaHH The review queues are there so the community can handle things, not so they can flag everything in the queue. If you *need* to flag something, the link to the post is there. Flagging shouldn't be the default response.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: This sounds a bit like "if we put the link there, they would flag everything" and "where the link is, flagging should be the default response". This can't be true. I am not arguing about that its still possible to flag, but it appears to me that leaving out the flag link (or other ways of interaction in other review queues) was a conscious decision, but I can't come up with any proper reason. "When we leave it there, people will all the time flag stuff" doesn't seem valid to me, unless it was happening in earlier times, and silly flagging really originated from there.

Comment: @PlasmaHH You said yourself that "a big part of the posts I flag is out of some review queues." The tools you should be using 99% of the time for review are already in the review UI. If you need to do something else, click through to the post and use the tools there. Yes, this is on purpose. The review queues are there to relieve moderators of some of the work of moderating the site, not to give them more work.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Ok, I can buy that. AFAIK some of the flags don't end up in the moderators queue, but rather in a(nother) review queue. Would it make sense to make at least these accessible? Browsing through the comments here, in linked and related meta posts, I get the impression that by not offering them, some people feel they have no other choice than to approve these edits (or maybe that opening the post and flagging is even discouraged for those exceptional cases). This would not add to the moderator queue, so I guess no harm possible and more options to do the right thing?

Comment: @PlasmaHH If opening the post was discouraged, we wouldn't link to it. It's already in a review queue. I wouldn't *object* to it being moved to a different queue, but I don't strongly think it needs to be. The tools to do the right thing are already in place. You can either reject the edit, or click through to the post and vote to delete it, or both.

Comment: @Soren I don't understand your point. I never said there was the option to delete *on the review UI*. It's on the post itself.

Comment: @BilltheLizard -- my point is that he is getting penalized for approving an edit to a question/answer which should have been deleted, but there is no such option in the reviewer interface.

Comment: @Soren I said that the person suggesting the edit did the wrong thing. They were already on the post and should have voted to delete. The reviewer can click a link to go to the post and vote to delete as well, but that wasn't the point I was making in my answer. (And of all the options in the review interface, Approve is definitely the wrong one.)

Comment: Fixing list formatting is a perfectly valid edit. Now, in addition to evaluating the appropriateness of an edit - even minor ones like this - I have to read the original post, understand the context and all the comments and determine whether or not the question/answer merits deletion?  And I'm temporarily banned from the review queue if I can't tell?  Oftentimes I approve minor edits that correct spelling or code formatting or general question formatting (assuming nothing else is modified) even if I don't understand the specific api or framework. I should just click "Skip" instead?

Comment: @Blackhawk Do you think it's a good idea to continue encouraging people to suggest edits to posts that should be deleted instead?

Comment: @BilltheLizard From the standpoint of giving them reputation points, no, but from the standpoint of punishing reviewers for not performing a "vote to close" review every time they perform an "edit" review, perhaps.  The best compromise I can imagine (the least burden on editors and reviewers) might be to remove reputation points for edits on questions that get deleted due to quality.  Incentive gone.

Comment: @Blackhawk I think that's already in place. Edit: Unless [this has changed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78147/1288), you lose the 2 reputation you get for a suggested edit if the post is deleted.

Answer (score 25):

I absolutely disagree with this.  While the answer was clearly not useful, the interface presented in the edit review queue does not provide the tools to handle that.

An example:

[image: edit interface for a question]

Can't comment, can't flag, can't vote.  For a question, you can't vote to close.

Those are the tools used to deal with garbage question and answers.  The scope of the intended action while going through a queue is indicated to me by the tools provided.  If you see a poor post in the "Close", "Reopen" and "Low Quality" queues, your action is obvious, and provided for in the buttons at the top.  For "First Posts" and "Late Answers", you can vote, edit, flag and comment on the review page.

Further, the queue often, as seen in the image, skips identical lines.  You can view them, of course, but that communicates to me that I may not need to see them to do my job.  If I am tasked with reviewing the overall quality of the post, then this is *not appropriate*.  To review the validity of the edit itself, I may not need more than a line or two of context, but to review the whole post, you should be shown the whole thing right off.

And for an answer, the content of the question is not available *at all*, not even in an expandable form.  How in the world is one expected to evaluate whether it addresses the question.  Just from the title?

Everything about this interface communicates that it's job is to review *only the edit*, and that the overall quality of the post is out of scope.  If that is not the case, these issues need to be fixed.

Comment: Agreed.  Seems like the problem was with the person making the edit, not with the reviewers.

Comment: Whether or not you want to deal with the post itself being bad, approving is always the wrong option. Reject it or Skip it, since [there is no shame in using skip](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip)

Comment: @femtoRgon Thanks for taking the time to illustrate this. This is one of my big issues about this whole topic.

Comment: There is no need to see the question at all to know that this answer is not an answer.  It's not that its incorrect, or that it incorrectly interpreted the question, the problem is that *it was posting a question as an answer*.  You don't need to see anything other than the answer to know that that's wrong.

Comment: "Can't comment, can't flag, can't vote. For a question, you can't vote to close." That's not a valid excuse for clicking "Approve" on this post. That was the dead last option in this case.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - Perhaps, but to clarify: No one approved *the post*.  They approved *an edit* to the post.  An edit that unequivocally improved a poor (unsalvageable) post.  I think the difference is significant, so I hope you'll forgive the nitpick.

Comment: That doesn't change a thing. "Approve" was the wrong choice.

Answer (score 7):

### TL;DNR

- The actions taken in this incident punish good-faith efforts by reviewers who don't have full moderator privileges
- It is not clear that punishing reviewers this way also discourages poor answers
- It is not clear that punishing reviewers this way also discourages edits to poor answers
- It is not clear (to someone at this privilege level, i.e. me) that punishing reviewers this way saves anyone's time, either reviewers or diamond moderators, if it does not *by itself* discourage low-quality behaviors.
- The review interface leads users (i.e. me) to draw several conclusions about what is expected of them, that are basically opposite to what some of the super-mods have been saying in their answers here.  That is a problem.

### Analysis

Looking at this in terms of reward and punishment, let's analyze what exactly has happened.

- A new user ("Poster") with 1 reputation provided a poor answer to a question.
- A user ("Editor") with (apparently) over 1000 reputation made an (apparently) good-faith edit to the poor answer.
- You ("Reviewer") decided to approve the edit in good faith in the review console.
- A Moderator temporarily banned you from doing reviews as a result.
- I cannot tell what if any action Moderator took against Editor.
- The answer is now gone, so at some point the answer itself was deleted.  I cannot tell by whom.

So given this information, what behaviors have been incentivized?  I cannot find any.

- Contributing poor answers?  It seems not, as the answer has now been deleted.  I believe that would reverse any reputation awards from upvoting that had occurred in the meantime.
- Making poor edits?  Mixed message at best.  Initially the edit was approved, but now the entire answer has been deleted.

But what behaviors have been disincentivized?

- **Poor review choices**.  This is plainly true, due to the existence of this question on meta.
- Contributing poor answers.  The answer is deleted.
- Making poor edits.  The answer is deleted.
- And of course, if doing something poorly is punished, the activity itself now carries risk, and requires care, and therefore takes more time than it might otherwise.  Posting, editing, and *reviewing*.

And now, how do these incentives and disincentives change if Moderator had not temporarily banned Reviewer?

- Plainly, the disincentive on poor review choices goes away; therefore review activity is less risky and takes less time.  I assume that the approval would be deducted from the count towards any badge when the answer itself was deleted, so this would become a neutral activity, not rewarded or punished.
- Poor answers?  I don't see how, if the answer is deleted anyway.
- Poor edits?  I don't see how, if the answer is deleted anyway.

If all this reasoning is valid, we may conclude that the punishment of Reviewer was *counter-productive* from a viewpoint of reward and punishment - assuming, of course, that people doing reviews is desirable.

Now let's consider whose time was saved and wasted in this temporary review ban.

- Moderator spent time doing the ban, that would not have been spent not imposing a ban.
- Is Moderator time otherwise unaffected?  Do edited answers take longer to delete than unedited ones?
- Reviewer's time was saved during the ban - because Reviewer is not doing any reviews.
- Poster's time is unaffected - the edit is still approved, and the answer still deleted, whether or not the ban is imposed.
- Editor's time is unaffected - the edit is still approved, and the answer still deleted, whether or not the ban is imposed.

I see only one way in which the punishment of Reviewer is beneficial from a viewpoint of time management: if it saves significant moderator time to delete poor answers when they have never been edited.  Otherwise, I find it is also *counter-productive* from a viewpoint of time management to punish reviewers this way.

I cannot help but notice that in the answers and discussion so far, users with full Trusted User privilege are nearly all in favor of your temporary ban, and users who have not yet earned the Access To Moderator Tools privilege (10k rep) are nearly all opposed to it.  (Including me.)  I find this conspicuous.  It points to the 10K reputation level being some sort of threshold where the reward/punishment balance changes from one side to the other.

So I conclude, the temporary ban from the review panel resulting from a poor review decision is either an unambiguously bad policy, or at best a trade-off where moderator time is saved at the expense of disincentivizing reviewers.

### Review Interface

While I don't see the interface as the crux of what *should* be done about such review decisions, I do agree with others that the review interface could be better designed.  The UI implies that the reviewer should consider the edit in a vacuum, without respect to attached comments or the antecedent question, and consider only the actions presented as buttons at the top of the page.

- If the correct behavior in the above case is to flag the answer, ***why isn't "Reject and Flag" one of the buttons***?  This is so *bleeding obvious*.
- If the edit should be considered in the context of the original question, *show the question*.  Screen real estate is a concern, but the question could be added below.  These users have lots of rep, so they're sophisticated, and anyway this is not the same screen; so I think it's OK to invert the presentation.
- It is not even clear whether the score we are shown is the score of the question or the answer in this case.  Especially if "the question matters", both scores should be shown.

Answer (score 6):

> why?

You approved an unhelpful edit

> Who makes those determinations?

A human moderator noticed your improper review and banned you.  As to which moderator, I wouldn't think it's all that relevant, but they may choose to post here and reveal themselves.

> As I understand it, it doesn't matter if the item being approved for an edit is an answer or not.

Taking time to edit non-answers posted as answers is putting lipstick on a pig.  It's just a waste of everyone's time.  You should just delete the non-answer instead of editing it.

> The review process for edits doesn't give you any context, so how would a reviewer know if was an answer or not anyway?

You only need to read the post to see that it's asking a new question (well, really it's just giving a list of requirements for code he wants, not really asking a question...), not posting an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please see my edit above.

Comment: @NathanA So you didn't know that you shouldn't be approving edits to crap posts that still merit deletion after the edit.  Now you know.

Comment: "A human moderator noticed" or better "Someone noticed and flagged a moderator"

Answer (score 5):

Well...you let someone polish a turd.

That answer really isn't a suitable answer to the question at all.  Look at it again in context - it's asking a question **inside of an answer**.

Context is key here - it's not answering the question at all.  It should have been deleted instead of edited.

EDIT: To address your concern, I feel that you're wrong.  You want edits to have lasting benefits for the site.  If the content you are reviewing doesn't have any value, then there's zero point to making the edit.  Hence, my earlier analogy.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please see my edit above.

Comment: I've replied as such in my answer.

Comment: True, but I didn't make the edit.  If anything, penalize the author of the edit.  I just reviewed their change, and considered it a valid edit to the existing post.

Comment: @NathanA *And you were incorrect in your evaluation that the edit was valid*.  That's the whole point here.  The editor's consequence *should* have come as a result of you rejecting the edit, but you didn't do your job correctly.

Comment: Whoa.  "Your job"?  Review is voluntary.  Punish good faith too much, and see what happens to this site.  Learn from Wikimedia's experience.

Comment: @wberry:  Call it "due diligence", then.  The idea is to be vigilant when it comes to edits; if we edit terrible answers, then the overall quality of the site's answers will suffer.

Comment: My bigger issue is this: "If the content you are reviewing doesn't have any value, then there's zero point to making the edit."  Key word zero - implies that the edit (and the review) has basically *no* effect.  Not a *negative* effect.  So it's a tree falling in the woods.  Why actively punish that?  Just delete the answer upon detection and move on.