# Can the type of post being reviewed be displayed more prominently?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

At times, it is hard to distinguish what type of content I am being asked to review.  If I have to scroll all the way to the bottom of the post and read some tiny text to determine if this is a question or an answer, I am less likely to help review things on SO.

I'm even less likely to review if I get penalized for approving a valid edit on an invalid answer (I thought I was reviewing a question).

Others agree with me [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261812/you-approved-edits-on-something-that-clearly-wasnt-an-answer), in the comments of the question.  I've been asked to officially request the post type to be displayed more prominently.

Comment: Particularly, on edit reviews.  Also, make it clear if the reviewer is meant to take in the consideration the context of the entire question/answer, or if it's simply the task of the reviewer to review the edit being made itself (without any overall context considerations).

Comment: It's also confusing in the context of tag wiki edit suggestions ([see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268765/shouldnt-rejection-reasons-for-tag-wiki-edits-be-changed)).

Comment: @JoshCaswell - looks like that question was asked less than an hour ago. my question was from nearly two years ago!  clearly mine is not the dupe, though I never got an answer...