# Shouldn't rejection reasons for tag wiki edits be changed?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, rejected-edits

I've suggested [this tag wiki edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5540419), which was rejected.

While I understand that it is subjective whether it was a good edit or not, I'd still argue that my clarification is useful (and I've explained it in the edit's comment).

But what's bothering me more is the reason, which says:

> This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost.

O_O? Obviously it changes the original meaning and the intent, doing exactly that was my intent. And often there is nothing wrong in "changing much" of tag wiki. This reason doesn't seem to make sense for tag wikis.

I feel that reviewers were confused and acted as if they were reviewing a suggested edit of a post (question or answer), not a tag wiki.

If my intuition is right, perhaps some UI changes may be suggested to make the difference clear? And maybe the lists of rejection reasons should be different.

My bonus question is should I proceed in suggesting this edit again?

Comment: That looks like a fine edit to me.

Comment: I'd say the reviewers did not pay attention and did not see this was an edit for a tag wiki, not a question or answer.

Comment: Yes, I really wish it was more immediately clear what type of post is being reviewed. This was suggested before, but unfortunately went nowhere, despite a good number of upvotes: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265992/can-the-type-of-post-being-reviewed-be-displayed-more-prominently.

Comment: I think it's a valid option to have, though it didn't seem to apply to the edit you made.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reviewers must not have been paying attention and did not realise this was a tag wiki edit. If you look at it as a question or answer edit, you can see why it might have been rejected.

I've [applied a variant of your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4913958/revisions); CSV does not strictly mean 'comma separated' anymore, although the name does imply that.

Comment: Yes, I've also presented the same suspicion. I somewhat cluttered my post with two things: this particular edit, and the general problem. Thanks for everyone their input, and thanks Martijn for your answer and for fixing the wiki! :-) (btw. you might want to include in your answer the relevant link provided by Reto Koradi in the comments above so it will be more complete)

Comment: Right now it means "character separated".

Comment: @Braiam: good one, need to remember that! :-)