# Confused on edits vs comments

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I would like some clarification of when to comment and when to edit an answer. The faq states

> Our goal is to have the **best answers** to every question, so if you see questions or answers that can be improved, you can **edit** them.

Furthermore it states of comments,

> Use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or answer.

Yesterday I had this [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6217243) rejected by 3 of 3 reviewers. Using .NET Classes in place of PowerShell cmdlets is an odd choice. I did not think much of it until today, when this [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6235523) was suggested to my answer. It passed 3 to 2, but the two rejections were for different reasons.

Given that my edit was reject, this edit should have **definitely** been rejected.

The next time I suggested an edit, stackoverflow admonished me for having my previous edit rejected. The rejection implies I should have commented, but I was not seeking more information nor a clarification. Further, I was trying to improve the answer. Where did I go wrong? Should I, especially given the 3-to-2 split on the edit of my answer, assume some valid edits will be rejected and some questionable ones will get through?

---

**Update:** I may have made too much of the comparison between the two edits. My real issue is that according to the faq I did the right thing, but the response to what I did was negative. The suggested solution was to comment, which goes against the faq. In the future, by what threshold do I go from commenting to editing? If my edit should have been a comment, shouldn't all edits be comments?

Comment: Generally, I'm a lot less tolerant of people editing questions than answers. Your edit was of a question, whereas the other edit was of an answer. Changing the content of the question can change the question in ways that alter the way one might answer it, especially a change to the code. Change the content of an answer may or may not change the answer, even a change to the code. In this case, I would have rejected both edits, but I can see why the edit to the answer passed: it's the same answer, just with expanded aliases.

Comment: Actually, my edit was to an answer as well.

Comment: Your first link is to an edit to a question, and that edit drastically altered the code in the question. With rare exceptions (formatting that does not have an impact), you should **never** change code in a question. Please carefully note the emphasis I've added to the word **never**. Changing code in a question can make a major impact on the meaning of the question itself. **Never** change the code in a question. The second should have been a comment noting that you could replace the full names with the aliases, rather than an edit to the code itself. I would have rejected it.

Comment: I've checked and rechecked. My edit changed Ansgar Wiechers' answer. It had nothing to do with the question. Look at my link, and the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893218/how-to-split-a-csv-file-depending-of-row-values/26893808

Comment: Is that the problem right there? Two of people reading this question, plus 3 other reviewers all thought I was editing the question? Why is it so unclear that I was editing the answer?

Comment: Just to beat a dead horse, why would Ansgar's supposed question start with "If I understood your **question** correctly"?

Comment: About the question vs. answer confusion, there have been requests before to label the post type more clearly in the edit review queue. For example here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265992/can-the-type-of-post-being-reviewed-be-displayed-more-prominently. Unfortunately that hasn't gone anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the edit you got rejected: Many reviewers are very hesitant to approve code changes in answers. Unless it's a minor change that looks like it fixes an obvious mistake, they will often be rejected. I think there are a couple of reasons for this:

- Reviewers will often not be familiar with the specific technical area of the question. So they will not be able to evaluate if the edit is correct. In case of doubt, many will decline the edit. Even though skipping the review would be the better option, IMHO.
- This is slightly more philosophical, but the way I see it, SO is a mix of different ownership models. To some degree, content is created in collaboration. You can edit content that other people wrote to improve it. On the other hand, the name of the author is prominently placed next to the post, which implies that the person who wrote the post has ownership of it. Therefore, substantial changes to the content are often frowned upon.

The second example you found, where somebody else's edit was approved, is indeed a pretty much identical case to the one that was declined for you. In the end, it often depends on who happens to do the reviews. The reviewer stats shown if you click the "More" link under the names of the reviewers can be enlightening. In this case, the stats of the reviewers who approved the edit are:

1. has approved 433 edit suggestions and rejected 95 edit suggestions
2. has approved 386 edit suggestions and rejected 15 edit suggestions
3. has approved 249 edit suggestions and rejected 131 edit suggestions

You can draw your own conclusions on how (non-)selective they are at approving edits.

Answer (score 6):

You have two people in the comments who erroneously thought that your edit was to a question, when it is in fact an edit to an answer. I looked at your case last evening. At first, I also thought you edited a question. I realized I was wrong when I read the first sentence of the answer. The issue may be with the GUI showing tags just under the answer. Since tags are associated with questions, this throws us off.

**The misidentification of the answer as a question may very well have played a part in the ultimate rejection of your edit.** Code edits in questions are very often rejected when they change the semantics of the code. Adding or removing white space to improve readability is okay. (When they really *improve* readability. Changing the style because one prefers a different style is not okay.) But edits that fix errors may be editing away the source of the OP's problem.

Editing away errors in answers is more likely to be acceptable. An edit that fixes a typo that could cause a syntax error (e.g. missing parenthesis) would likely be accepted. However, an edit that replaces a name with an alias of this same name is not likely to be accepted. The choice of name is a matter of style. Such edit is not actually *fixing* something.

A user that would like to suggest an edit that would most likely not be accepted always has the option to leave a comment or post an answer of their own. I've sometimes posted such answers myself. "Bob's answer is correct but I prefer to..."